# Combine vlookup formulas into one formula with condition

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup

I'm trying to combine  4 different Array formula's. I have tried some suggestions on this site but they didn't work.

Here's a couple I tried:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(K6>0,K6<=15),VLOOKUP(D5,Data!$F$2:$L$7,2,FALSE),0))  
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(K6>=16,K6<=99),VLOOKUP(D5,Data!$F$2:$L$7,3,FALSE)))*K6
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(K6>=100,K6<=249),VLOOKUP(D5,Data!$F$2:$L$7,4,FALSE)))*K6
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(K6>=250,K6<=499),VLOOKUP(D5,Data!$F$2:$L$7,5,FALSE)))*K6
```

Hope someone can help make this formula.

Comment: Why are you using arrayformula? For which part? it's not clear what the end result is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

First have to mention that using of `ArrayFormula` is doing nothing in your formulas. So I've got rid of it in my solution.

I've made helper table to make it one formula:

[image]

Then I've made 3 steps.

## Step 1. Find column of vlookup

Use vlookup with sorted table to find the number of column to return:

`=VLOOKUP(K6,$R$2:$T$5,2)`

## Step 2. Find the multiplier

I see in the first formula you don't multiply `*K6`

But you need one formula to match all conditions. So we use `power` of number:

1. `K6 ^ 0 = 1`
2. `K6 ^ 1 = K6`

To get the power I used my helper table again:

`=VLOOKUP(K6,$R$2:$T$5,3)`

## Step 3. Combine the formula

The last thing is to get all this done in one formula:

`=IF(AND(K6>0,K6<=499),VLOOKUP(D5,Data!$F$2:$L$7,VLOOKUP(K6,$R$2:$T$5,2),FALSE),0)
*K6^VLOOKUP(K6,$R$2:$T$5,3)`

I still use `if-and` in order to prevent errors in my `vlookup` part of the formula.

Comment: Thanks, got it now

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an option to @Max Makhrov. I modified the 'IF' statement to put the '`^`' inside the core VLOOKUP section. If K6 breaks the `if-and` rule then the final '`^`' VLOOKUP would likely error as out-of-bounds. So

```
=IF(AND(K6>0,K6<=499),VLOOKUP(D5,Data!$F$2:$L$7,VLOOKUP(K6,$R$2:$T$5,2),FALSE)*K6^VLOOKUP(K6,$R$2:$T$5,3),0)
```